# No accuracy when recording CLLocationPoints in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, polyline

I'm working with a app to record walks, but I can't get the polylines to be as smooth as it looks in other apps, like runkeeper. I have tried with different activityType, desiredAccuracy and so on. I have tested on iPhone 5c, 6s and 7. It always looks like the example photo, it was recorded out in the open without any buildings near. Is there something I'm missing?

This is my `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `locationManager` and `rendererFor  overlay`:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myLocations = []
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.activityType = .fitness
    manager.distanceFilter = 5
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //Map
    logMap.delegate = self
    logMap.mapType = MKMapType.standard

    manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

    logMap.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 1)!
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == .notDetermined || status == .denied || status == 
.authorizedWhenInUse {
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.requestLocation()
    }else{
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        logMap.showsUserLocation = true
    }
    if status != .denied {
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
        manager.requestLocation()
    }
    if status == .authorizedAlways {
        logMap.showsUserLocation = true
        logMap.mapType = MKMapType(rawValue: 0)!
        //logMap.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingMode(rawValue: 3)!
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations 
locations: [CLLocation]){

    if(isLoging==true){
        if(myLocations.count > 1){
            self.distance = self.distance + 
Int(locations[0].distance(from: myLocations.last!))
        }
            myLocations.append(locations[0])
            setDistance()
    }
    // paint line
    if (myLocations.count > 1){
        let sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
        let destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2

        let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
        let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
        var a = [c1, c2]
        let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
        logMap.add(polyline)
    }
}
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
}
```

Result: 
[image: And no, I didn't walk like that!]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `distanceFilter` to `k​CLDistance​Filter​None`. This will notify you of every movement, but will consume the most battery.

Even if you are outside of a building you still don't get perfect accuracy. 
If I were to guess other fitness app assume that you don't run through buildings and stuff, so they adjust you path to match streets.

I know for a fact that Strava shows my path through buildings and gardens, because they don't get perfect accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to get best accuracy to get your location everytime.

```
override func loadView() {

    print("loadView called")

    // Enable some map settings

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    map.settings.myLocationButton = true
    map.settings.compassButton = true
    map.settings.scrollGestures = true
    map.settings.zoomGestures = true
    map.delegate = self

    view = map

}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("ViewDidLoad called")

    // Configuring location manager.

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

}
```

Add Delegate in ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locationManager function called")

    // Fetch current location coordinates

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
    currentLatitude = locValue.latitude
    currentLongitude = locValue.longitude
    print("Current Location = \(currentLatitude!), \(currentLongitude!)")

    // Zoom to current location

    let target = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude!, longitude: currentLongitude!)
    map.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: target, zoom: 17)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    //DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.75, execute: {self.webResponse()})

}
```